# Access to Jsonapi in Maintenance Mode?

Tags: drupal

I need to put a Drupal 9 site in maintenance mode. This will take a few hours. But the site serves as a data source for several other systems via Jsonapi. Therefore the Jsonapi should remain functional in maintenance mode.

In the Core MaintenanceMode.php this would work.

```
public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
....
if (strpos($path_info, '/jsonapi/') === 0) {
  // Do not apply maintenance mode for JSON:API routes.
  return FALSE;
}
```

But of course I can't change the core. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In regular ways, you should not use the json_api under maintenance mode beucase maintenance mode uses to perform database updates and this also may impact jsonapi.

But you can patch the drupal core and bypass the maintenance mode on it.

Here is how:

```
composer require cweagans/composer-patches
```

Just need to add this reference to your composer.json file and then, customize the composer.json files with your patch.

Here follows the source code and the docs.

https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches

https://docs.cweagans.net/composer-patches/usage/defining-patches/